# spring-authorization-server not working as expected, throws error 500 due to jsession problem

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

So after gaining some experience with OIDC on the client side
and Keycloak as a provider,
I wanted to take a closer look at Spring's authorisation server.

Unfortunately I cannot get the most simple example running as expected.
So I have setup a server like inside the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#developing-your-first-application). But also tried the linked example there.

While standard login via form login with no URI parameters just works fine,
the moment I will append standard parameters like in the examples below, it will break.

`http://localhost:8081/oauth2/authorize?client_id=oauth2-proxy&response_type=code&scope=openid`

It will immediately throw an error on the backend like this:

```
2023-01-13T09:10:34.837+01:00 DEBUG 4126 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:9000/login;jsessionid=542C9BFAE8B26DD2DB33597F8040993D
2023-01-13T09:10:34.840+01:00 DEBUG 4126 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] s.s.w.f.HttpStatusRequestRejectedHandler : Rejecting request due to: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"

org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"
```

It will still continue but then eventually bail out with a 500.
Any help appreciated, increasing the log level does not help here

```
2023-01-13T09:10:41.666+01:00 DEBUG 4126 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-01-13T09:10:41.679+01:00 DEBUG 4126 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2023-01-13T09:10:41.681+01:00 DEBUG 4126 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

I would expect the login to work and not bail out with a 500:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http
            .getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http
            // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
            // authorization endpoint
            .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
                )
            // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )

            // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
            // authorization server filter chain
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user1")
                .password("user1")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("oauth2-proxy")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:8081/")
                //.redirectUri("http://localhost:8081/login/oauth2/code/oauth2-proxy-oidc")
                //.redirectUri("http://localhost:8081/authorized")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .scope(OidcScopes.EMAIL)
                .scope("message.read")
                .scope("message.write")
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }
```

`application.yml`:

```yaml
#application
server:
  port: 8081
  tomcat.threads.max: 20

#monitoring
management:
    endpoint:
      health:
        show-details: always
    endpoints:
      web:
        exposure:
          include: "health,prometheus,heapdump"

logging:
  level:
    root: debug
    org.springframework: debug
```

Comment: thank you for both comments
it's a standard spring boot jar with tomcat
as from the examples 

I've attached securityconfig and application.yml above

i already tried the cookie version , that still gives me a 500 .. but 
maybe it was the wrong property .. and someone can provide the rights ones

thank you

Comment: also the standard spring boot example linked above
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/default-authorizationserver

has the same "problems" at least inside chrome and safari ...
i would expect that to work out of the box

Comment: Following your hints, i added an DefaultHttpFirewall
While that got rid of jsessionid error .. i still get an error page with error 999 at the and and without any further details inside the logs whats going wroing
found other posts related to oauth2server with the same problem
will investigate further

Comment: @Andreas Your are trying to login with `client_id=messaging-client`, but you didn't registered such a client. Also you configured: `port: 8081`, but in your URL you use port 9000.

Comment: yeah no .. i used
http://localhost:8081/oauth2/authorize?client_id=oauth2-proxy&response_type=code&scope=openid

my bad .. mixed up my code with another request

if it would be that simple i would sure get clear exceptions ..
already spend hours debugging inside the spring security code

authentication is always successfull but than a redirect to /error occurs with an error code of 999 and a 500 thrown somewhere without any indication what is going wroing .. very tedious honestly .. so any help appreciated

Comment: i am somehow sure that it is related to the redirect uris
i do not provide inside the request, so it seems to be required params according ti the spec .. but providing one doesnt change anything

also change the spring config to
http://localhost:8081/login/oauth2/code/oauth2-proxy

which should be the right one ... 

at least on the clientside its usually /oauth2/code/{client}
but also to no avail and no error message thats helps

Comment: so for the record i am at least on step ahead
this url works
http://127.0.0.1:8081/oauth2/authorize?client_id=oauth2-proxy&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=state&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8081/login/oauth2/code/oauth2-proxy

so the redirect_uri has to be there and it has to exactly match the one inside the spring configuration

also important is to use 127.0.0.1 .. no localhost no nothing 
if you enable "trace" logging you will see some exceptions 

so at least the 999 is gone, but i now end up with a 404 from the redirect_uri

Comment: so for the 404 i cannot find a solution
as the /login/oauth2/code/oauth2-proxy will result in a 404 i suspect that this never gets exposed correctly

interesting thing is, that the auth server example test dont have a positive test, they also just test for a 404, assuming that there is no index page ... 

so if someone nows how to solve the final 404, this would be much appreciated

Comment: I nearly found the answer by myself now
Forget about the 404 .. that is (of course) because the callback endpoint has to be provided by the CLIENT Application.
In my case this is currently the OauthProxy ... 
I think it would work now in theory, but i ran into some CSRF trouble, which i also had with Keycloak because of Domain Mixups

So in general .. the original is mostly related to the redirect_uris and Spring not providing good errors inside the log .. which is really add.
Would also help if the method would be called setALLOWEDRedirectUris ... because thats what it is in an nutshell

Answer (score 0):

so to sum things up, these are the things i've learned:

- your url HAS to contain a redirect uri, as it is a required field
- the redirect uri is specific to your CLIENT so look there for the right url
- the redirect uri has of course to be registered at the server, inside the RegisterdClientRepository
- but to be specific, this one will only be used for pattern matching if the one provided via the url is known to the server
- the redirect uri MUST NOT contain localhost, at least for the standard configuration this is disabled
- you SHOULD enable loglevel "trace" for spring security to really see all the errors

If you follow those rules you shall be successful .. other you will be pretty much bumped with a generic error 999 inside the frontend without further clues ...

If you want to have more details, I've compiled a short video together with a Github Repo connected
https://youtu.be/ZrG7fdTDjzw